# Dynamic scale domain in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to define my x-axis:

- minimum value should be now()
- maximum value should be automatically determined (just as if the domain of the scale would have not been defined)

  ```
     "encoding": {
   "y": {
     "field": "Reference",
     "type": "nominal",
     },
   "x":{
     "field": "Date",
     "type": "temporal",
     "scale": {"domain": [now(), 1618000000000]}}
  ```

I also tried to use an expression to set-up now(), to no success:

```
"scale": {"domain": ["expr":"now()", 1618000000000]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close with the second attempt; you just need to put braces around the expression statement:

```json
"scale": {"domain": [{"expr": "now()"}, "2021-05-01T00:00:00"]}
```

Here's a full example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUkUG8IATAAykCMAtOQMx1UAq55cbH5IANCMumJwqAXx4FoQspVrkALE1btObXv1SZ49MRKIkK1OgFZFK5dz4DNcUiIC6YkAFsIAJwDWJFAEsAdsT4MXwBjAHswPwBzeFAADxiQADNvDBQwEkIAkCgATwAHKSInPNDXVDUsYNQhAlCXPzxQDFi81xJfUIB3AAoAShBHA1kTchYzLhAHRxyE5NT0uHVBNVyCkgBHNAhfKG8YXcRiEWOgA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2021-03-01T00:00:00", "value": 1},
      {"date": "2021-04-01T00:00:00", "value": 3},
      {"date": "2021-05-01T00:00:00", "value": 2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "scale": {"domain": [{"expr": "now()"}, "2021-05-01T00:00:00"]}
    },
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If instead of setting the domain limits, you just want to ensure that `now()` appears as part of the domain, you can use a domain [unionWith](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#domain) statement:

```json
"scale": {"domain": {"unionWith": [{"expr": "now()"}]}}
```

This will create an automatically calculated domain that contains the current date.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for the fast and thorough answer. I can see that the linked example works just fine. Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce it in the Vega-Lite block of Airtable. There I get an error message:  "Incorrect type. Expected "null"." I'm not sure if it has to do will limitations of the Vega-Lite block of Airtable. I will post another question.

Comment: I suspect Airtable bundles an outdated version of  vega-lite